# Javascript minify or obfuscate code before browser loads JS

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

I need a solution to obfuscate or minify my javascript code before the client loads any of my important javascript files. I need my code to have all the comments for future development, but load a minified or obfuscated version to my users.

The reason I want to do this is because my code is heavily commented. I need my comments for future updates, but I don't want prying eyes reading my comments as that's asking for trouble. Thanks!

Comment: you mean in runtime ? why don't you minify the files before deployment.

Comment: The usual practice is to keep a plain version of your code for development, and also create a minified version that will be served to the browser. Gulp will help you with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) for minification and concatenation of JS files (and other types).

Complete details on how to integrate minification using [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

If you also desire to concatenate your files and deliver one single file, check [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat).

To speed up the development you should also use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) that allows you to watch over changes to your files and run the defined tasks.

Basic setup for minification:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        my_target: {
            files: {
                'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also check out the sample [Grunt-file](https://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) in which you should define all your tasks.

Comment: Thanks Catalin! I'm going to go over the documentation now. Does grunt automatically update the output file each time I add additions to my code?

Comment: @LogicalNonsense, yes. You can use grunt-contrib-watch. I updated my answer.

Comment: Grunt is hairy. Look at Gulp, much easier to configure and use.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I'll also look into gulp.